# how to store dynamically created textbox value to db

Tags: php, jquery, loops, dynamic

i have a code for dynamically created textbox,radiobutton,checkbox..and my question is How can i save the dynamically created textbox checkbox ,radiobutton into MYSQL Database .

```
<div class="maindiv">
<div id="header"></div>
<div class="menu">
<button id="namebutton"><img src="images/name-img.png">Name</button>
<button id="emailbutton"><img src="images/email.png">Email</button>
<button id="addressbutton"><img src="images/contact-img.png">Address</button>
<button id="checkboxbutton"><img src="images/check-img.png">CheckBox</button>
<button id="radioaddbutton"><img src="images/radio-img.png">Radio</button>
<button id="reset">Reset</button>
</div>
<div class="InputsWrapper1">
<div id="yourhead">
<div id="your">
<h2 id="yourtitle">Your Form Title<img src="images/edit-form.png"></h2>
<h4 id="justclickid">Just Click on Fields on left to start building your form. It's fast, easy & fun.</h4>
</div>
</div>
<div id="InputsWrapper"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

here is the link for my code [link](http://jsfiddle.net/7mjrup84) ....and its working fine for me but not working in jsfiddle above link

Comment: here is the link for my code https://jsfiddle.net/7mjrup84/ ....and its working fine for me but not working in jsfiddle above link

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest serializing your form's content into a string and simply storing that string in a field called something like `form_data`.

To do this, you would need to ensure that all of your elements that you want to save are nested within a `<form>` tag. Once you have that you can call the [`.serialize()`](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) function on your form element.

> From [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/):
>
> The `.serialize()` method creates a text string in standard URL-encoded
>   notation. It can act on a jQuery object that has selected individual
>   form controls, such as `<input>`, `<textarea>`, and `<select>`: 
>   `$( "input, textarea, select" ).serialize()`;
>
> It is typically easier, however, to select the `<form>` itself for
>   serialization

```
var form_string = $("#my_dynamic_form").serialize();
```

This serialization will give you a string in the following format:

```
single=Single&multiple=Multiple&multiple=Multiple3&check=check2&radio=radio2
```

As you can see, this string can be easily saved into the database in a single column. To decode the values in PHP (for example), you can use the [`parse_url()` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php):

```
$form_string  = "single=Single&multiple=Multiple...";
parse_str($form_string, $form_data);
```

The `$form_data` will now contain the following data:

```
Array ( 
  [single] => "Single" 
  [multiple] => "Multiple"
  ...
)
```